# Adding child view dynamically to layout, only knowing layout id

Tags: android, view, viewgroup

I'm using the AppIntro, and am trying to add a static view on appear on top all the fragments, I figured instead adding that view manually to all the fragment XML, I am trying to create another class that extends AppIntro so this view will appear in all my intro activities..

This is what I have so far..

```
public class AppIntroMod extends AppIntro {
    private static final String TAG = AppIntroMod.class.getSimpleName();
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            final Button btn1 = new Button(this);
            btn1.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.btn_expand);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(30, 120);
            params.topMargin = 200;

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(getLayoutId(), null);  //getLayoutID() returns R.layout.intro_layout which is from the library
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            );
            vg.addView(btn1, params);
            ...
}}
```

I'm having a hard time since AppIntro doesn't let you use setContentView() to add your own activity layout, otherwise the library would not work.

Thanks!

Comment: After the `super.onCreate()` call, `intro_layout` will already be inflated and attached. You don't want to inflate it; you just need to find the root `View` in it, which is a `RelativeLayout`. Unfortunately, that doesn't have an ID assigned to it, so you can't grab it directly with `findViewById()`. However, it has a `ViewPager` as a direct child, so you could find that, and grab its parent; e.g., `RelativeLayout root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.view_pager).getParent();`. Then add your static `View` to that.

Comment: That is really detailed, I'll try it out, thank you!